# Trying to override initWithFrame with extra options

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am trying to update the UITableViewCell view with a different type of theme.
I have a few themes but cannot get them to work correctly.

```
@interface CustomRowBackground : UIView {
CGColorRef topStroke;
CGColorRef lightColor;
CGColorRef darkColor;
CGColorRef bottomStroke; //also known as separator
CGColorRef borderColor;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame topStroke:(CGColorRef)top lightColor:(CGColorRef)light   darkColor:(CGColorRef)dark bottomStroke:(CGColorRef)bottom borderColor:(CGColorRef)border;
@end

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame topStroke:(CGColorRef)top lightColor:(CGColorRef)light    darkColor:(CGColorRef)dark bottomStroke:(CGColorRef)bottom borderColor:(CGColorRef)border
{
   self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
    topStroke = top;
    lightColor = light;
    darkColor = dark;
    bottomStroke = bottom;
    borderColor = border;



}
return self;
}
```

Now in my UIViewController,  .h file, I extend the UIColor class with a helper method

```
@interface UIColor (BIExtras)
+(UIColor *)colorWithR:(CGFloat)red G:(CGFloat)green B:(CGFloat)blue A:(CGFloat)alpha;
@end
```

then in the .m I write this

```
@implementation UIColor (BIExtras)
+(UIColor *)colorWithR:(CGFloat)red G:(CGFloat)green B:(CGFloat)blue A:(CGFloat)alpha {
return [UIColor colorWithRed:(red/255.0) green:(green/255.0) blue:(blue/255.0) alpha:alpha];    
}
@end
```

then I try to set the desired gradient that I'm after for a particular row.

```
TaskDisplayCell *cell = (TaskDisplayCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:TaskCellIdentifier];
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    cell.backgroundView = [[CustomRowBackground alloc]  initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.tableView.bounds.size.width,40) 
topStroke:[UIColor colorWithR:119 G:119 B:119 A:1].CGColor 
lightColor:[UIColor colorWithR:92 G:92 B:92 A:1].CGColor 
darkColor:[UIColor colorWithR:70 G:70 B:70 A:1].CGColor 
bottomStroke:[UIColor colorWithR:76 G:76 B:76 A:1].CGColor 
borderColor:[UIColor colorWithR:110 G:110 B:110 A:1].CGColor]; 
}
```

Note: I am not sure if this is the way to do it. I just want to initialise the background with a different gradient theme.

Anyways, it gives me an error. If I manually write in the drawRect an assignment of a [UIColor colorWith] method, that works. If I instead allow for code reuse, it crashes.

Any ideas?

Ben

Comment: "It gives me an error" is no help. What error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem I see in your program is that you do not perform memory management of your `CGColorRef`s -- ARC (assuming you have it enabled) does not manage non-ObjC objects for you. You must retain and release these manually. So in both ARC and MRC, you must retain and release these manually.

This is the basic form:

```
@interface CustomRowBackground : UIView {
    CGColorRef color;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame color:(CGColorRef)pColor;

@end

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame color:(CGColorRef)pColor
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        color = CGColorRetain(pColor);
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    CGColorRelease(color), color = 0;
// [super dealloc]; if MRC
}

- (CGColorRef)color
{
    return color;
}

- (void)setColor:(CGColorRef)p
{
    if (color == p) {
        return;
    }
    CGColorRef prev = color;
    color = CGColorRetain(p);
    CGColorRelease(prev);
}
```

Comment: Yes I do have ARC enabled. What are non-objective C objects? Is there a list of them somewhere so I know which ones have to be retained and released manually. By retain? I only know of retain via one way. That is by creating a property for the class. Then I would have to release it inside the dealloc method, right? Can you show me what I should have written instead? thanks, Ben

Comment: @Ben `struct objc_object` is an objc object, and `id` is `struct objc_object*` and all its descendants are objc objects -- that includes `NSObject` and all of its subclasses. blocks are also objc objects. everything else is not an objc object -- C types, CoreFoundation (CF) types, CG types, C++ types is a small set of examples types which are not objc types. the list is endless :) for `CGColor`s, you can simply use CGColorRetain and CGColorRelease. will throw an ultra-basic example up…

Comment: It would be simpler for Ben to just change his ivars to type `UIColor *` instead of `CGColorRef`.

Comment: @robmayoff true +1, but that would just evade understanding, if an explanation were not provided.

Comment: @Justin, I had a look at the code, did some more reading and came across a simpler way to add the CGColorRetain in the cellForRowAtIndexPath. darkColor:CGColorRetain([UIColor colorWithR:70 G:70 B:70 A:1].CGColor). Not too sure how I am going to release them. Is this a good approach so far or should I be sticking with your approach?

Comment: @Ben I wouldn't recommend the approach you propose. Ownership and lifecycle are not very clear. Those details should be abstracted by the class so you don't need to remember to retain it whenever you create. You could simplify my example if you do not need accessors. You could also create little functions so you do not have redundant code (e.g. for the setter).